# Help required SIGQUIT in Bash

Tags: bash, gnu, signals

/tmp/trap.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
echo parent
trap signalCaught HUP INT QUIT TERM

signalCaught() {
    echo "SIGNAL DETECTED I am the parent."
}

SLEEP=10
for i in $(seq $SLEEP -1 0); do
    echo "$i"
    sleep 1
done

/tmp/trap2.sh 2>&1 | tee -ai /tmp/garbage.txt

echo " --- terminating \"$0\" "
```

/tmp/trap2.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
echo child
trap 'echo signal caught in child' HUP INT QUIT TERM
read JUNK

SLEEP=10
echo sleeping for $SLEEP seconds
sleep $SLEEP

echo " --- terminating \"$0\" "
```

When I run /tmp/trap.sh, and allow it to call trap2.sh, SIGQUIT is only caught by the parent process (trap.sh). The "echo signal caught in child" is not echoed. I *assume*, then, that the child does not catch SIGQUIT.

Is there a reason the child does not catch QUIT? It does catch INT

Answer (score 3):

`tee -ai /tmp/garbage.txt` is catching `SIGQUIT`.  So for example, when both `trap.sh` and `trap2.sh` are running, you have something like:

```
% pstree 62655
-+= 62655 nicholas -zsh
 \-+= 62867 nicholas /bin/bash ./trap.sh
   |--- 62889 nicholas /bin/bash /tmp/trap2.sh
   \--- 62890 nicholas tee -ai /tmp/garbage.txt
```

When I press `^\`, it gets delivered to the bottom of the tree (pid 62890):

```
% sudo dtrace -n 'proc:::signal-send /pid/ { printf("%s -%d %d",execname,args[2],args[1]->pr_pid); }'
dtrace: description 'proc:::signal-send ' matched 1 probe
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  1  19556          sigprocmask:signal-send Terminal -3 62890
```

If I explicitly `kill -QUIT 62889`, then it does indeed print `signal caught in child`.

(Thanks to the commenter for making me challenge my assumptions: my previous answer here was completely wrong.)

As @Random832 mentions, process groups are used for delivering signals.  In pstree output, `=` indicates the leader of a process group.  You can also see with `ps -j` output, `trap.sh`, `trap2.sh` and `tee -ai ...` are in the same group:

```
% pstree 64261
-+= 64261 nicholas -zsh
 \-+= 64551 nicholas /bin/bash ./trap.sh
   |--- 64554 nicholas /bin/bash /tmp/trap2.sh
   \--- 64555 nicholas tee -ai /tmp/garbage.txt
% ps -jxp 64261,64551,64554,64555
USER       PID  PPID  PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT       TIME COMMAND
nicholas 64261 64260 64261 90c3998    1 S    s002    0:00.12 -zsh
nicholas 64551 64261 64551 90c3998    1 S+   s002    0:00.01 /bin/bash ./trap.sh
nicholas 64554 64551 64551 90c3998    1 S+   s002    0:00.00 /bin/bash /tmp/trap2.sh
nicholas 64555 64551 64551 90c3998    1 S+   s002    0:00.00 tee -ai /tmp/garbage.txt
```

Comment: How is it delivered to the 'root' process rather than to the foreground process, i.e. the one that actually dies if you _haven't_ set a signal handler? And why is he seeing different behavior for SIGINT? Please provide documentation.

Comment: Thanks for challenging my sloppy thinking.

Comment: I've done some research, and it looks like there's something to do with process groups and signals being delivered to every process in a group... can pstree show the process group id of each process?

Comment: The terminal app sends it (Terminal in my case, I also checked and xterm does the same thing).  You can see that in the DTrace output.

Comment: but tee man page shows -i, --ignore-interrupts: ignore interrupt signals. Then 'tee' should be ignoring my signals, right?

Comment: It ignores `SIGINT` if you use `-i`, yes; not `SIGQUIT`.